# Why is react masonry component not working?

Tags: css, reactjs, masonry

I'm testing out react-masonry-component with some images.

But for some reason the images didn't turn out correctly in a masonry-like arrangement. Instead they just line up in one column like below.

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Below is my code for the component and CSS.

: [image].

Gallery Component:

```
import React from 'react';
    import Masonry from 'react-masonry-component';
    import './grid.css';

    const masonryOptions = {
        transitionDuration: 0
    };

    const imagesLoadedOptions = { 
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        percentPosition: true,
     }

    class Gallery extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state={elements:[
                {src:"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/orange-tree.jpg"},
                {src:"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/submerged.jpg"},
                {src:"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/look-out.jpg"},
                {src:"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/one-world-trade.jpg"},
                {src:"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/drizzle.jpg"},

            ]}
        }


        render() {
            const childElements = this.state.elements.map(function(element,index){
                return (
                     <div key={index} className='grid-item'>
                         <img src={element.src} />
                     </div>
                 );
             });
             return (
                <Masonry
                className={'.grid'} // default ''
                elementType={'div'} // default 'div'
                options={masonryOptions} // default {}
                imagesLoadedOptions={imagesLoadedOptions}
                disableImagesLoaded={false} // default false
                updateOnEachImageLoad={false} // default false and works only if disableImagesLoaded is false
            >
            <div className="grid-sizer"> {childElements}</div>


               </Masonry>
            );

            }
    }

    export default Gallery;
```

CSS File:

```
/* ---- grid ---- */
.grid {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;    
    margin: 5px
}

/* ---- grid-item ---- */
.grid-sizer{
    width: 33.333%;

}
.grid-item {
    width: 33%;
    height: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.grid-item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with your grid-sizer element. I would suggest getting rid of the CSS styling on that class.

```css
/* ---- grid ---- */
.grid {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;    
    margin: 5px
}

/* ---- grid-item ---- */
.grid-item {
    width: 33%;
    height: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.grid-item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
```